# Complex :includes for Eager Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, eager-loading

I'm trying to create a pretty complex eager load; I’d like to modify the second statement, not the first. I need to create a join on the second statement that includes a column from another table.

Everything I try modifies the first statement and leaves the second as is. If there’s another way to accomplish the same task without N+1 queries, I'm open.

This:

```
Conversation.joins(:phones)
            .where('phones.id' => 2)
            .order('last_message_at DESC')
            .includes(:messages)
```

Generates:

```
SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" 
 INNER JOIN "conversations_phones" 
  ON "conversations_phones"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id" 
 INNER JOIN "phones"
  ON "phones"."id" = "conversations_phones"."phone_id" 
 WHERE "phones"."id" = 2 ORDER BY last_message_at DESC

SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" 
 WHERE "messages"."conversation_id" IN (10, 11) ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

Makes sense, but not where I want to be.

I can write the needed second statement with something like this:

```
Message.joins(:message_tags)
       .select('messages.*, message_tags.status as read')
       .group('messages.id, message_tags.status')
       .order('messages.id')
       .where(:message_tags => { :user_id => current_user.id })
       .where(:messages => { :conversation_id => [10, 11] })
```

Which correctly generates:

```
SELECT messages.*, message_tags.status as read FROM "messages" 
 INNER JOIN "message_tags" ON "message_tags"."message_id" = "messages"."id" 
 WHERE "message_tags"."user_id" = 2 AND "messages"."conversation_id" IN (10, 11) 
 GROUP BY messages.id, message_tags.status 
 ORDER BY messages.id
```

Basically, I want the more complex messages select to replace the simpler one so I can call @conversations.first.messages.first.read without creating a new query.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to add some conditions to an association:

```
has_many :messages, -> { select('messages.*, message_tags.status as read')) }
```

and then something like:

```
Conversation.joins(:phones)
  .where('phones.id' => 2)
  .order('last_message_at DESC')
  .includes(:messages => :message_tags)
  .where(:message_tags => { :user_id => current_user.id })
```

Comment: Definitely getting closer; I didn't think of changing the has_many statement. Would something like scopes be useful for this?

Comment: you can only joins/includes on associations, so I can't see scopes being particularly helpful. what's the outstanding problem?

Comment: The problem is that I'm still learning Rails. A message has_many tags, but the user should only see theirs. I'd like to include their tag as a column in the message, using their user_id to fetch it from the tag join table.

Comment: `User has_many :message_tags, through: :messages` `User.includes(:message_tags)`, voila.